# Edit link greyed out?

Tags: support, editing

When I open the question [Counting the Number of Simple Paths in Undirected Graph](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20246/5038), I notice that the "edit" link below the question is greyed out and not clickable.

Is there a way to suggest an edit to that question?   I'm sure there is a reason why the edit link is greyed out and not available; does anyone know what that might indicate?  Not a big deal, I am just curious and wondering if I should do anything differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think out might be because there was already an edit waiting approval at that time.